# Transform java function (verify bank account number) to objective c

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have this code in java to verify a bank account number, what I'm trying to do is to convert it into objective-c but I think my code isn't working has intended, here is the code:

JAVA 1:

```
public boolean isValid(final String accountCnumber,
        final ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
    if ((accountCnumber == null) && optional) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        if (accountCnumber == null) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            boolean result;
            if (accountCnumber.length() == 12) {
                final String auxAccountNumber = accountCnumber.substring(3,5)+ accountCnumber.substring(0, 3) + accountCnumber.substring(5, 12);
                Integer principalCounter = 0;
                Integer counter = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < auxAccountNumber.length() - 1; i++) {

                    principalCounter = checkData(auxAccountNumber,
                            principalCounter, i);

                }

                final Integer cont = (principalCounter + 10) * 10;
                counter = cont - principalCounter;
                final String lastAux = counter.toString().substring(counter.toString().length() - 1);
                final String last = accountCnumber.substring(11);

                result = lastAux.equals(last);
            }
            else {
                result = false;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

My objective-c Attempt 1: (I think the error is with the passing from .subString to the NSRange)

```
-(BOOL)accountValidation: (NSString *)accountCnumber
{

    if ([accountCnumber isEqualToString:@""] || accountCnumber == nil) {
        return false;
    }else{
        Boolean result;
        if (accountCnumber.length == 12) {

            /*
             000200041901
            */

            NSString *auxAccountNumber = @"";

            NSRange range1 = NSMakeRange(3, 2); //20
            NSRange range2 = NSMakeRange(0, 3); //000
            NSRange range3 = NSMakeRange(5, 7); //0041901

            NSString *subString1 = [accountCnumber substringWithRange:range1];
            NSString *subString2 = [accountCnumber substringWithRange:range2];
            NSString *subString3 = [accountCnumber substringWithRange:range3];

            NSLog(@"subString1  20=%@",subString1);
            NSLog(@"subString2  000=%@",subString2);
            NSLog(@"subString3 0041901=%@",subString3);

            auxAccountNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",subString1,subString2,subString3];

            NSLog(@"auxAccountNumber = %@",auxAccountNumber);

            int principalCounter = 0;
            int counter = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < auxAccountNumber.length - 1; i++) {

                //principalCounter = checkData(auxAccountNumber,principalCounter, i);

                principalCounter = [self checkData:auxAccountNumber p:principalCounter counter:i];

            }

            int cont = (principalCounter + 10) * 10;
            counter = cont - principalCounter;

            NSString *strFromInt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",counter];

            NSString *lastAux = [strFromInt substringFromIndex:[strFromInt length]-1];

            NSString *last = [accountCnumber substringFromIndex:11];

            //result = lastAux.equals(last);

            if ([lastAux isEqualToString:last]) {
                result = true;
            }else{
                result = false;
            }

        }
        else {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

JAVA 2:

```
private Integer checkData(final String auxAccountNumber, final Integer pCounter, final int i) {
    Integer principalCounter = pCounter;
    Integer counter = 0;
    Integer aux;
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        counter = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(auxAccountNumber.charAt(i))) * 2;
        if (counter >= 10) {
            counter = counter - 9;
        }
        principalCounter = principalCounter + counter;
    }
    else {
        aux = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(auxAccountNumber.charAt(i)));
        principalCounter = principalCounter + aux;
    }
    return principalCounter;
}
```

My objective-c Attempt:

```
-(int)checkData:(NSString *)auxAccountNumber p:(int)pCounter counter:(int)i
{
    int principalCounter = pCounter;
    int counter = 0;
    int aux=0;
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        NSString *s = auxAccountNumber;
        const char *c = [s UTF8String];

        counter = c[i] * 2;

        if (counter >= 10) {
            counter = counter - 9;
        }
        principalCounter = principalCounter + counter;

    }else {
        NSString *s = auxAccountNumber;
        const char *c = [s UTF8String];
        counter = c[i] * 2;
        principalCounter = principalCounter + aux;
    }
    return principalCounter;

}
```

Sorry for the long post, but I really need this :)

**EDIT**  I have these valid bank account numbers for testing @"000200041901" and @"001200144174" the result from the method "accountValidation" must return true but the problem is that it always returns false.

Comment: This sounds off-topic for SO. Maybe try here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You _think_ your code isn't working as intended? Then how are we supposed to know? Please perform some tests and then get back to us when you have a specific question.

Comment: Sorry, my bad for the vague question, I edited it for further clarification.

Comment: Try debugging both java and ObjectiveC versions simultaneously while monitoring the values step by step. I believe that if you set some breakpoints at the right places you'll find the error yourself.  If you come back with a question such as 'how do I extract a character from a string?', THAT would be a specific question, and it would be very easy to help you.

Comment: I can tell quickly that the checkData:p:counter: method is incorrect: aux is always 0. Factoring out the code common in the if and else would make it easier to see what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of the second method re-written with a little better naming and elimination of redundancy:

```
- (int)checkDataAuxAccountNumber:(NSString *)auxAccountNumber pCounter:(int)pCounter digitIndex:(int)digitIndex {
    NSString *digitString = [auxAccountNumber substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(digitIndex, 1)];
    int digit = [digitString intValue];

    if (digitIndex % 2 == 0) {
        digit *= 2;
        if (digit >= 10) {
            digit -= 9;
        }
    }

    return pCounter + digit;
}
```

Convert the first method in a similar manner.
Then create some test code for both Java and Objective-C code.